# Are websockets used in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In shiny architecture (client and server model), are web-sockets requests used? Or is it only http request that is sent to server?

I know this is very direct question, but wanted to understand the back end working of shiny?

Comment: You can see the dependencies here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shiny/index.html. It does rely on the `httpuv` library for websocket communication between the client and the server. There's nothing stopping you opening as many websockets in pure JS on the client side which then you can pass back to the server https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html

Comment: So you mean to say, only in JS we can open web socket but not on R ? Is this what you meant?

Comment: R is single threaded, so unless you use library such as `promises` https://rstudio.github.io/promises/index.html, and handle the connections yourself its best to handle it on the client side, in JS and pass on the objects to the server via one socket

Comment: [Here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/are-websockets-used-in-shiny/128738) the RStudio Community cross post can be found.